# Facebook Graph API field matching value

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm using Facebook Api 2.8 and I'm trying to "query" a data array of thumbnail where the field "is_preferred" only matches "true" and I have no luck with it.

Query:
`10154642642791633?fields=thumbnails{is_preferred}`

URL: [Facebook API Thumbnail GET query](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=10154642642791633%3Ffields%3Dthumbnails%7Bis_preferred%7D&version=v2.8)

The field "is_preferred" is a bool and I can't use something like thumbnails.is_preferred(true) or thumbnails{is_preferred(true)}, thumbnails{is_preferred=true} or nothing like that... nothing works.

This is to avoid getting like 8 or 10 values from the data "thumbnails" with a huge response if I get something like 25 videos at once.

Hope this is possible! It would help me a lot. Thanks in advance!

DOCS: [Facebook API Video Thumbnails](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video-thumbnail/)

Comment: from the docs it looks like it should be ?fields={is_preferred=true}, or am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like all "=" are "Syntax error" for Facebook api.

Comment: Have you tried escaping and url-encoding it?

Comment: Not sure what that is... all my test was with the endpoint and Graph Explorer.

Comment: also, it seams like this is the actual documentation for 2.8 and not the link you put up there: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/thumbnails/

Comment: Oh, ok... but still shows the "is_preferred" parameter.

Comment: No no, that's the point. The 'is_preferred' parameter is used when CREATING a thumbnail. The READING (a.k.a. GET) endpoint has no parameters.